# Disallow use some functions in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have an application which reads a textarea and runs the textarea as a PHP file.

The textarea content is saved in a txt file and runs with `eval(file_get_contents('myfile.txt'));` but I want only to allow user to use `echo`, `if` statement, `for`, `while` without using `mysql(i)` functions and some other functions like `unlink`.

**EDIT**
A little bit more explaining: How can I disallow in a specific file using php functions like mysql and file functions ?

Is there any options to do this?

Comment: eval is evil so why you use it? but to your task ... maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723623/restrictions-for-php-eval

Comment: @donald123 why eval is bad?

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php

Comment: or this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: @donald123 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, you could try php sandbox: 
https://github.com/fieryprophet/php-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

well, maybe you can use this solution.
php [override_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php).
if you really want to use eval, and make it safe. you are going to work hard. but basically if you don't want to write your private php parser like customEval(). you can just override php native functions

```
override_function('file_put_contents', '$a', 'echo file_put_contents not allowed...;');
```

the problem with that solution: if you will need one of this functions after the eval(), you can't use them. unless you'll override the override. 2nd problem, the overriding list might be long (: