# php advanced string splitting

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I've spent the better part of 2 days searching on all the ways to split strings in PHP, but none of them got me anywhere. I need to be able to split the following string format into arrays, and then split each of those arrays into sub-arrays.

The data is a journal of register sales. Each transaction is in the same format and the only difference in string length per transaction is the amount of items purchased. Here is an example: **(This receipt is one single hex stream, all empty spaces are a space character (\x20) and all '.' are (\x00).  Again, these are all 1 single line just edited to make it easier to look at)**

```
    DATE           07/13/2014            MON...
         PLU#491320                          ..
          SPRITE T1                    $0.75...
          CUSTOMER DATE OF BIRTH  02/05/1978...
         PLU#820050                          ..
          SMIRNOFF VODKA LT T2        $13.99...
          TAX1 AMT                     $0.06...
          TAX2 AMT                     $1.42...
          .T.O.T.A.L              .$.16..2.2...
          .C.H.A.R.G.E            .$.16..2.2...
    NO.000002 REG01 EMPLOYEE 2    TIME 18:09..€
```

Basically I'm looking for:

```
    Array {
           [0] = Date: 07/13/2014
           [1] = PLU#/Tax/Price: 491320 & T1 & 0.75, 820050 & T2 & 13.99 (no spaces)
           [2] = Tax: T1 & 0.06, T2 & 1.42 (no spaces)
           [3] = Transaction No.: 000001
           [4] = Register: 01
           [5] = Employee: Employee 2
           [6] = Time: 17:59
    }
```

I've tried `preg_replace`, `preg_split`, `substr` and `str_split`, using `strpos` and searching for the string position for each section. Nothing worked. I can clear the spaces, but it screws up with stuff like `Employee name`, which may have an actual space in it.

Are there any other ways of splitting strings besides what I just listed? I've tried dozens of substr and preg functions and none of them helped me. I've spent enough time with trial and error from google searches, I may as well ask if someone knows something I haven't come across.

Comment: You might author a simple lexer or parser. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002617/php-lexer-and-parser-generator

Comment: Or here: http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can split it with "\n" to get lines, then trim excessed spaces and with regex get left and right parts.

EDIT:
I just realized that you dont want named array for left and right collumn. You just wanted split based on lines.

```
explode("\n", $input) //double quotes are necessary
```

Comment: This kind of worked, this also made me realize that I forgot to mention these aren't in "lines" but rather one single stream of hex.  This split each transaction after the first / in the date, so rather than the next line starting with DATE, the line before ended with DATE07.

Comment: Then post sample in original form, well figure something out. Btw did you try [chunk-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)?