# How to choose a proper parser generator for PHP?

Tags: php, regex, xslt, yacc, lex

Some programmers say they are "... sick of using regex to parse things that really shouldn't be parsed with regex" (see this [popular @nickf comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2093228/287948)). Other ones, like me, prefer to program more with PHP (and [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)) and avoid another framework (like [Lex/Yacc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2093228/287948))... But not "so more", and that is the first question:

When we must avoid to create a (complex) PHP parser, migrating to a real "[parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator) engine"?

The second question, that completes the first, is "What the best PHP tool-kit" for  parsing complex things?  Today, 2013, there are a standard interoperable parser-content, XML (or [SimpleXML arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), etc.), and "standard parsers", like [DOM API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model),  [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and [XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php).

As [I sketched](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648476/287948), perhaps there are no "best solution", but a *good practices* recipe to select sometimes a solution, then another.

**Summarizing**: 1) "When should we leave pure PHP or PHP+RegEx, to use *parser generators*?";  2) "What the best *parser generators* for PHP, or the recipe/context/condictions for select the best ones?"

---

(add in edited version)

I think readers will appreciate generic discussion, but, to give a guideline, here some **scope**:

- (answering @HugoDelsing) In general I "dont care how it works but want to get quick results". In a few cases I need optimization, when I "want full control over everything".
- (answering @bizzehdee) In recent years, I am parsing many kinds of text strings: raw text of [controlled vocabularies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_vocabulary);   [Lex URNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(URN)); raw text of References/Bibliography and another stiling text, like [Vancouver Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_system); [CSS strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets); dates; e-mail text; units and equations (to recognize, normalize, and eventually convert). In another times, I developed simple command line tools.

---

***Curiosity*** (was my motivation to post this question): [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648476/287948) about use of "PHP alternatives for Lex/Yacc approach" is  oscilating every month, with positive and negative "useful votes"... Perhaps it is only an indication that there are "hate and love" behaviour, but, by other hand, can be a good question!

Comment: so, what are you parsing? are you trying to parse the PHP its self? or are you trying to parse "something" using PHP?

Comment: The common interpretation from your intro is based on confusing matching and parsing. Not sure there is a generic answer for your actual question, as there aren't generic tools that apply to everything. Depends on your input lingo or representation to be parsed with. Surely `unpack()` is more suited for  (please note the quotes) "parsing" binary data than a lexer or a regex (not implying it's infeasible though).

Comment: If you want to learn how something works and want full control over everything you do: `Do it yourself`. If you dont care how it works but want to get quick results > Use something somebody else wrote for you. Atlast > If you are coding above your knowledge, there is a good chance somebody else wrote better/more efficient code and it might be wise to use it

Comment: PHP does not have a decent parser generator. By "decent" I mean one that is actively maintained/developed, and has decent documentation.

Comment: for the record: question has been re-posted to Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190557/how-to-choose-a-proper-parser-generator-for-php